# Microsoft Report designer undoucumented error

Tags: rdlc

While updating the dataset in rdlc report file ,I got below error.

Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalCoreSDK, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I resolve this as i am unable to work on rdlc anymore .Kindly help here.

Comment: The PayPalSDK needs to be installed on the server.

Comment: I am running report on my local system through VS2010 .Everything is running fine ,Already have the references of the dll PayPalCoreSdk in my project.Eariler it was fine but not now.

Comment: That is not a good idea..reinstall VS2010.Any other way..It is working fine in VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

This question is kinda old already, but just in case someone searching for an answer for this problem gets here, I'll say this has happened to me several times. Apparently there's some problem when working with a solution containing multiple projects. You gotta remove all references to other projects on the project you are trying to change the rldc report, once you do that u'll be able to refresh your report source in design. Hope this helps someone.